# Did WMD 3 ever come out?

Tags: discussion, markdown, editor

Here's what the WMD [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/wmd-new/) page says:

> Version 3.0 should be released in February/March 2009 and will a major rewrite making use of jQuery.

Has this been released? What is the status of the project?

Comment: ..........what?

Comment: We only do 2D on Meta, no statues; they're too hard to put a freehand circle around.

Comment: 3d freehand *spheres?*

Comment: Yes, spheres.  A true fan would buy several hundred monitors and mount them on a sliding rack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm back on the case.  No timeline yet but I'll update as things progress.

Sorry for the delay...  I had a Ph.D. to finish and I started a new job.

Comment: friggin' slackers

Answer (score 2):

We're still discussing this with Dana. I just emailed him the other day. He just submitted his thesis so in theory he might be more free to work on this. I'll advise as I know more.